# calculate distance between images?

Tags: python, distance

I want to calculate the distance between images in one distribution, for more explanation if we have MNIST data set I want to calculate the distance between them and it will be high because the images are varied, images belong to class 1 and others belong to class 2 and so on ...
and the distance between the images in the same class for example class 1 is will be low.

So, how I can do this? and whats appropriate distance measure for this? is KL or EMD or another measure?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can look into `triplet loss` for minimizing embedding distance between similar class and maximize embedding distance between different classes. MNIST example and explanation links,

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet

https://www.coursera.org/lecture/convolutional-neural-networks/face-verification-and-binary-classification-xTihv

https://towardsdatascience.com/contrasting-contrastive-loss-functions-3c13ca5f055e

https://gombru.github.io/2019/04/03/ranking_loss/

Another approach is to use general pretrained image classifier convolutional layers to extract important features of images and flatten output into a vector. This is similar to word embeddings where distance can be calculated. Similarly, using this embedding from image can be used to calculate similarity with others with various distance methods such as [Cosine Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), Euclidean Distance.

This repo is useful for deep learning based image similarity,

https://github.com/ryanfwy/image-similarity

**Some alternate method,**

You can try repo below for image hashing to get image similarity based on various methods. Likely this will not work good various distortions and variations.

https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash

Image similarity with Earth Mover Distance,

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404775/calculate-earth-movers-distance-for-two-grayscale-images

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/749429/